# What is the difference between "splitting something" and "dividing something"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, verbs

What is the difference between "splitting something" and "dividing something"?

When do people say *split* and when do they say *divide*?

Comment: I think the differences in connotation and usage here may be interesting, although the question might be stronger with some context or examples to focus on.

Answer (score 9):

I would say the distinction is that **splitting** implies crude or forceful, you split a log (or an infinitive) while **dividing** implies deliberate precision, you divide a circle into quadrants ( or Gaul into three parts )

Comment: I wonder whether this is more of a difference in register because _dividere_ is Latin, while _splitten_ is Germanic?

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with this.  If a few people go out to dinner together, when presented with a check they might say "Let's just split it," implying a crude, simple split amongst all parties, or "Let's just divide it," implying figuring out what everyone owes individually.  Not a perfect rule ("Can you split the check?") but it works.

Comment: I think divide emphasizes the measurement of the resulting parts while split emphasizes the act of separation. That may be why you have to add *equally* when you say, "Let's split it equally. "

Answer (score 2):

Splitting might mean actually separating or chunking something, while dividing may not.

Answer (score 2):

I undestand these words like this:

split:  not all equal (lets split 10 in 5   4,2,1,1,1,1) or all equal (split in 'even' parts 2,2,2,2,2).

divide: all equal ( divide in 'always' in even parts) lets divide 10/5 '2,2,2,2,2' all equal.

Comment: my definition is for quantities

Answer (score 1):

> When do people say *split* and when do they say *divide*?

[**Divide**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divide) and [**Split**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/split)

What's the difference between "***splitting*** something ***in half***" and "***dividing*** something ***in half***"? I'd say both terms can be used interchangeably in the following scenario.

If a restaurant bill was $36.00, each person would pay exactly $18.00.

A couple (married or otherwise) can ***split up***.
If they later divorced, you can say they had to ***divide*** their assets ***between*** the two of them. It's quite common to say; they ***divided*** (something) **fifty-fifty** in this case.

You have to ***divide*** (your) ***time*** between work, recreation and family duties.
You also divide work responsibilities.

In maths (BrEng) math (AmEng) we use the word, divide, for making divisions,
 e.g.,  ***divided*** 20 ***by*** 4; ***divided*** 5 ***into*** 35; 3 ***divides*** 9.

In idiomatic expressions we say:

- ***Split hairs*** (to try to make petty distinctions) *not* Divide hairs.
   
  E.g.; "Stop *splitting hairs* over such minor details."
- I've got ***to split*** (I must go away immediately, I don't have time)
- To ***split*** people ***up*** ( break up two people because they are fighting or for example talking incessantly)
  *The teacher split the two boys up because they were behaving badly.*

Comment: Another example would be **splitting** wood (as in chopping with an axe)- if one went out to **divide** wood, it would imply that there was something quite different...